# How to send attachment in slack bot using SlackClient for node.js

Tags: node.js, slack, chatbot

I want to send image, text and bullet point with different colours. I am only able to send back message using
 `slackClient.sendMessage(botSays(parsedResp, witError, message) , message.channel);`

But I don't know how to send attachment. Any help will be appreciable

Thanks

Comment: Which slack client are you using here??

Comment: The SDK provided by slack in github, here is the link https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Attachments can be sent to user via IncomingWebhook or Web Api. There are many html text formatting and image attachment also possible. [Slack Attachment api](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments)